# Rails 5: No method error when rendering partial without using Activerecord reload method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having difficulty understanding the reasoning behind why i am unable to render a partial using the first method as compared to the second. Changing my code to `<%= render partial: @article.reload.comments %>` works. The comment form is a remote form  submitted with Ajax.

I am getting an undefined method 'email' for nil Class on the article show page (i have gravatar set up for the user), with below line highlighted.

```
gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
```

**This error message only shows when i refresh the article show page after i have submitted some comments through Ajax.**

**Rails console when submitting a comment form:**

```
Started POST "/articles/et-incidunt-labore/comments" 
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"content"=>"this is a new comment"}, "commit"=>"Add Comment", "article_id"=>"et-incidunt-labore"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "et-incidunt-labore"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("content", "article_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "this is a new comment"], ["article_id", 154], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2017-11-04 11:42:10.099567"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-04 11:42:10.099567"]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT

  Rendering comments/create.js.erb
  Rendered comments/_comment.html.erb (1.4ms)
   (7.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = $1  [["article_id", 154]]
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (19.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 47ms (Views: 18.4ms | ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)
```

**Rails console when reloading the article show page:**

```
Started GET "/articles/et-incidunt-labore"
Processing by ArticlesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"et-incidunt-labore"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."slug" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["slug", "et-incidunt-labores"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Article Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 154], ["LIMIT", 1]]

  Rendering articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application

  Comment Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["article_id", 154], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Comment Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."article_id" = $1  [["article_id", 154]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered collection of comments/_comment.html.erb [2 times] (5.9ms)
  Rendered articles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (27.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 80ms (ActiveRecord: 32.9ms)


ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):
    3:     <div class="card-block">
    4:       <div class="row">
    5:         <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2">
    6:           <%= gravatar_for(comment.user, size:50) %>
    7:         </div>
    8:         <div class="col-md-11 col-xs-10">
    9:           <b><%= comment.user.name %></b>

app/helpers/users_helper.rb:4:in `gravatar_for'
app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___3274541922963352908_69873959519460'
app/views/articles/show.html.erb:57:in `_app_views_articles_show_html_erb___4339274147925900264_69874017658060'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:17:in `catch_not_found'
```

**articles/show.html.erb**

First method:

```
  <% if @comments.exists? %>
      <%= render @comments %>
  <% else %>
      <p> There are no comments yet.</p>
  <% end %>
```

Second method:

```
  <% if @comments.exists? %>
      <%= render partial: @article.reload.comments %>
  <% else %>
      <p> There are no comments yet.</p>
  <% end %>
```

**Articles controller**

```
  def show
      @article = Article.friendly.find(params[:id])
      @comments = @article.comments
      @new_comment = @article.comments.new
  end
```

**comment/comment.html.erb**

```
<%= comment.content %>
```

Rest of code related to this comments feature can be found on [this other Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47101211/rails-5-ajax-comment-appended-only-if-a-comment-exists) i posted.

Comment: have you checked the user object in the console ?

Comment: The error happens when calling `email` on a `user`. But there is no `user` in your code examples. Please post the code related to the error.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Hi, the error only appears after i reload the article show page. The user id of the comment is committed to the database after submission, User model is loaded in rails console and the user who submitted the comment is selected.

Comment: can you put a puts user.inspect above the gravatar statement and check the value of user in the terminal

Comment: @DhavalChheda i have stripped down the comments section of the article show page to just <%= comment.content %> and placed <= comment.user.inspect %> above and this is the results in browser: #<User id: 1, email: "test1@test.com", created_at: "2017-11-03 14:45:55", updated_at: "2017-11-03 14:46:36", name: "Test1">. Page now renders without any errors if i remove any code that has user association with the comment.

Comment: @DhavalChheda Testing out Comment.last.user.name in the rails console returns a result: Test1, which means the association has been done properly?

Comment: so what does user.email return?